# Using DokuWiki, how to record some informations to my database when user creates a new page

Tags: database, dokuwiki

In recently, I am a new to DokuWiki. I try to login my dokuwiki by mysql using "authpdo" plugin successfully. Now I have a question bothering me a lot. That is **how to record some informations to my database when user creates a new page**. Currently, I can't find the plugin which meets my needs. Please give me some idea, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DokuWiki uses flat files, not DB.

If you want to trigger an event on page creation I'd suggest you either

- Write a plugin or
- A separate watchdog which will do what you need when a new file (page) is created.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your thought is very useful.